# Unity3D, Glass Shader, prevent rifts

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, vuforia, 3dsmax

I'm new to Unity and 3D and currently working on a 3D model of a smartphone. I have a Mesh that uses Standard shader with glass material. This mesh covers all of the surface, and is able to fill in any rifts that exist on the model.
My glass material looks like this:

[image]

The properties:

[image]

The model:

[image]

The problem is that this shader is black, it's covering other elements of the model, like camera, if I remove it, the model will look like this:

[image]

which is ok, but you may see that there are little gaps near to the camera, the rifts:

[image]

I have no idea how to fill this gaps and use glass shader in the same time.
Also, I cannot use Standard shader, because it doesn't work on mobile devices.
I tried to apply any other Glass Shaders with lower LOD, which seem to work, but the gaps still remain.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure these are not reflections? Change your skybox and see if the appearance of the "rifts" change.

Comment: Tried to remove the skybox and it seems to work, but  then the lightning is gone and my model turns black

Comment: You are not experiencing the problem that you think you are experiencing. The white parts are reflections which are perfectly normal. They are not rifts. If you put a bright red skybox in the scene the rifts will be red. My recommendation (if this really bothers you) is to average the normals on the edge of the "rifts" so that the reflection edge is not so sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I played around with the Standard Shader and the main problem you have is that it has no transparency at all. You won't be able to look through it if it has no alpha.

What I did to get results that seemed "okay" is:

- I set the rendering mode to `Transparent`
- I set the color to `#0024050C`
- I set the Metallic to `0`
- I set the Smoothness to `0.9`
- I kept everything else on default

There may be a comparable version for the Standard (Specular) setup:

- Same values as above
- Specular to `#181818FF`
- Source to `Specular Alpha`

And as far as I know, the Standard Shader should work on mobile with some features disabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the above configuration result is the same (see last picture)

Comment: Could you elaborate what your problem is on the last picture? I really don't see the problem.
If you have any optical rifts there as you describe it, no glass shader will fix this, instead the model needs to be fixed.